# 'Had a bad thing' and 'We're having a bad thing'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, colloquial-language

> 1. You had a bad thing that day.
> 2. You were having a bad thing that day.

Could you tell me the difference in meaning between sentence 1 and sentence 2?
I feel there must be a difference in meaning.

Comment: These are sentences that a native speaker would almost never write or speak. Where did you find them?

Comment: I heard that in the film. Are you a native speaker?

Comment: Yes, assuredly so. In what film did you hear these two sentences?

Comment: The name of the film is ' The time traveller's wife'.

Comment: Neither of those sentences are spoken in the film "The Time Traveler's Wife." The line _"You were having a bad day"_ is in the film. Is that what you mean to cite?

Comment: yes, maybe you are right. What is the difference between 'You were having a bad day.'and 'You had a bad day.'

Answer (score 1):

The implied meaning is:

> You had a bad thing [**happen**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/happen) that day.

The verb should be *had happen*. *happen* could be omitted in informal speech.

With only *had* as the verb (as in your example), it would mean you *possessed* a "bad thing". Unlikely, but we would need to know what the "bad thing" was, in context.